# NHibernate mapping many-to-many with specific order

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I have a table of `Users` and a table of `Profiles`. One user can have many profiles and a profile can have many users. An additional requirement is that the user's profiles should persist their specified order when saved to the database. Therefore I have the following relationships:

[image: tables]

How can I properly map this to classes with NHibernate? Is the only way to create another class like `UserProfile` that has an `Order` property and references the `User` and `Profile`? Is there a sleeker technique to this? I'd like to avoid this since it would add *another* layer of abstraction that isn't necessarily needed.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually found the *correct* way to solve this problem.

FluentMappings mappings should use **`AsMap(indexColumnName)`** or `<map name="Profiles"><index column="Order" type="integer" /></map>`.

```
// Inside the UserMapping (or an AutoMappingOverride).
this.ManyToMany(u => u.Profiles).AsMap("`Order`"); // "Order" is the column we want!

// Which produces this SQL - SQLite in my case:
create table ProfileToUser (
    User_id INT not null,
    Profile_id INT not null,
    "Order" INT not null,           // Exactly what I wanted.
    primary key (User_id, Order))
```

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this question asked several times and I don't think I've seen a **great** solution without creating the **UserProfile** entity.

One thing you can do is to only reference this entity from within the Users or Profiles class.  You could do something like this for example when adding new profiles to a user:

```
public virtual AddProfile(Profile profileToAdd, int order)
{
    //Create middle man object
    UserProfile newUserProfile = new UserProfile(this.Id, profileToAdd, order);
    this.UserProfiles.Add(newUserProfile);
}
```

This may not be perfect in your case but if you want to abstract this **middle man** away such that you only deal with it in your entities I think the above example gives you a start.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I'm going to change my answer as the accepted answer because it uses NH directly to solve this problem! Hope this helps you too :).